# In Atom, is there a package to autoformat long method calls into multi-lines?

Tags: python, package, coding-style, styles, atom-editor

In Atom, I'm looking for a way to auto-format long python lines like this:

before:

`bar = call_very_long_func_lots_of_params(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7)`

after:

`bar = call_very_long_func_lots_of_params(
    param1, 
    param2, 
    param3, 
    param4, 
    param5, 
    param6, 
    param7, 
)`

Are there any packages that help with this? Or any tricks? I find myself tediously taking a while to doing this kind of style formatting and would like to try and be more efficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the atom default multi select:

highlight the first comma within the parenthesis, and then do ctrl(cmd for mac) + d multiple times until you've highlighted all of `,`.

Now press `right arrow` (->) key, you should see cursors after each `,`.

press `enter`, which will shift each param to a newline except the first argument, which you can manually shift to newline.